# Long layover in Narita Airport Tokyo

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, layovers, transit-visas, nrt

I am travelling from India to Vancouver with my family which includes my wife, my 5-year-old daughter, and my 9-month-old son. We all have Indian passports.

We have a layover at Narita Airport Tokyo for 11 hours 30 minutes and want to book a hotel.

Do we need a visa to go outside the airport. What else can we do?

Comment: What does the Embassy of Japan in India say?